# Can SignalR be used to update clients which are servers by itself?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr

I'm trying to implement a Server which is a Asp.Net WebApi. This server is accessed by so many child services(let it be web servers). Can SignalR be used to update these child servers so that the child servers can update all the clients attached to them?

Answer (score 0):

SignalR is a Server <> Client technology, it can be used Server <> Server but its better to use a Service bus like nServicebus or MQ to pub / sub between services.

edit: If its for scalability only you can use SignalR scaleout features

Comment: In my case (server-server communication), Is there an effective and reliable callback mechanism like signalr?

Comment: I would checkout nServicebus if I were you

Comment: You should also check out pservicebus